# Get the result of a command as a variable in salt stack to modify iptables

Tags: iptables, salt-stack

I'm trying to put a new rule into iptables. What I would like is to put the rule into the penultimate line number (ie just before the DENY ALL statement). eg.

```
[vagrant@controller ~]$ sudo iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
5    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

then,

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -t filter -d 192.168.33.10 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

would be:

```
[vagrant@controller ~]$ sudo iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
5    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.33.10        state NEW
6    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

the issue is that I can not figure out how I can automate this with salt without explicitly knowing what the last line number is? Is there a way of running a command in salt stack and use the result of that command as a variable for the jinja template?

```
sudo iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers  | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any simple way to do this the way its described above.  Some of the work-arounds that come to mind:

1. Define the last rule such that it depends on (i.e. `require`s) the one you need to insert. Salt would then make sure that they are in the right order.
2. Create an additional iptables chain.  Insert a jump to the new chain somewhere into the original config, then alter the rules in the chain as needed.  This gives you a lot of flexibility.
3. Write a shell-script which does what you want and call it with `cmd.run`.  Quite inelegant but requires fewer changes to other parts of the config.

Neither of those options is perfect and may not suit your use-case.  However, combining the first to methods will get you pretty far and also result in an over all cleaner setup.